# Automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS in AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I want to redirect all of my HTTP requests to https in AWS. I use ELB for ssl certificate and using ubuntu(64-bit) os.

Answer (score 7):

You have two options:

1)  Use cloudfront in front of your ELB, and configure it to force everything to HTTPS

2)  Add a rewrite rule to your web server configuration to redirect to https.  Note that you will need to check X-Forwarded-Proto to determine if the original request was secure or not.

Answer (score 6):

The new Application ELB can redirect HTTP to HTTPS. Just open `Listeners` tab and follow `View/edit rules` link for the `HTTP : 80` listener. Then, you just edit default rule, remove default action and select `Redirect` option. Here you can set protocol (default is https), define custom port, modify server name, path, query string etc.

Comment: Way better handling the redirect at the ELB than the server if using ELB. Good catch here, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### 2019+

### AWS Application Load Balancers now supports HTTPS redirection.

On the console go to `EC2 > Load balancers > your load balancer > listeners`

Here you should have 2 rules: **HTTP : 80** and **HTTPS : 443**

You just have to:

- edit the **HTTP : 80** rule
- remove the **forward** rule and add a **redirect** rule to port 443 (picture 1)
- save and you should see something like picture 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible, that we could not see this option in germany and its only in us.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use only ELB to redirect request from HTTP to HTTPS. You must install some Reverse Proxy tools (like nginx or vanish, apache) to redirect all HTTP Request to HTTPS.Your ELB will listen both HTTP/HTTPS but your server will rewrite HTTP requests.
For example from aws https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/